# IE6 & IE7 How to obtain the selected option object form the select box

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html-select

I have a code like this:

```
var a = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex];
```

If I execute:

```
alert(a);
```

Using FF, Chrome, Opera, etc... I get:

> [object HTMLOptionElement]

Which is exactly what I want.
If I use IE6 or IE7, I get:

> [object]

With no expected Option properties at all.
This means that there is no TextNode as a childNode and no value property. How can I solve that problem?
Also if I try to use that node to add to another select box IE throws an exception:

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.
```

I was requested to make a program that is compatible with IE6 but I can't find a way to make it work. I need to move Option objects around and IE7 is not allowing me.

Edit by request:
Context HTML

```
                <select id="identification">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>

                    <select id="toBeFilled" multiple>
                </select>
```

Important note:
What I'm making **NEVER** knows the list of names and ids of the document. It only knows the nodes which it will use to work in the document.
When I state Node I mean, for instance, what document.getElementById() returns.

Comment: Couldn't you use jQuery? $('select').find('option:selected')....job done.

Comment: @Alistair Laing "job done", didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var a = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex];` will definitely give you an `Option` object (or `HTMLOptionElement`) in all browsers, IE 7, 6, 5, 4 and possibly 3 included (although IE may not give you a particularly helpful value when you call `toString()`, as you've observed). This will have `text` and `value` properties that reflect the text and value of the option. If this isn't working for you then there's a problem elsewhere in your code.

As for transferring options between select boxes, I'm not so sure on this, but if in doubt you could just create a new `Option` and add that to your new select box:

```
var newOption = new Option(a.text, a.value);
```

Comment: I'll try doing that. Seems like the only way to do that that IE6/IE7 understands.

Answer (score 0):

`var a = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;` will help you

(Alerts can only print Strings and Numbers, but no objects. You can use "console.log( a )" in Firebug and IE8+ with developer Toolbar

Comment: Nope. I get the empty string. I need the value not an empty string

Comment: Can you post the HTML where the JS is on?

Comment: The alert prints the toString() of the object.

Comment: In that case IE6 and IE7 show the empty string. Meanwhile, Those option doesn't have the value attribute, this one has